# Dart: how to reference methods of classes

Tags: dart

While writing library documentation I need to be able to reference (i.e. link to) methods from other classes (in the same library) but with the same method name (i.e. reference the delegating method from the docs of the one that is doing the work).

I have tried ClassName.method (does not work) and directly using the method (references the same class method).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this question about dartdoc? Like `/// This method [ClassName.method] ...`

Comment: yes, the generated docs do not have links, it is treated like regular text

Comment: I guess you should create a bug report because navigation within DartEditor works. AFAIK dartdoc bugs are managed in a github/dart-lang/xxx repo (probably dartlang.org)

Comment: I am not sure where to report it so I just entered it the first result in google: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=22144 - if its not the right place I will submit it wherever it must be.

Comment: Sorry, the message didn't contain the link when I saw it the last time. Thanks for adding the link to the issue.

Answer (score 2):

```dart
/// [B.someMethod] ..
/// [someMethod] ..
class A {
  void someMethod() {

  }
}

/// [A.someMethod]
/// [someMethod]
class B {
  void someMethod() {

  }
}

/// [A.someMethod]
void main() {
  new A().someMethod();
}
```

All references in the doc comments work for me in this example, but sometimes DartEditor shows them only as links after a delay or after some other edits.

Comment: Did not work for me : I tried regenerating the docs several times and yet in the resulting html the [...] part is kept as it is (i.e it is not a hyperlink but regular text). In my case the two classes are in separate files but part of the same lib. Currently I use the [text](link) workaround, but this is error prone. I will try putting everything in the same file as per your example.

Comment: Your question was not clear to me. The syntax seems fine because navigation works in DartEditor this way.

Comment: Maybe it is indeed bug in docgen. Will test some more and submit a bug when I am sure how it works.

Comment: Could be a bug in docgen or in the viewer. It is probably worthwhile to look at what the JSON that's produced says. It might be that docgen doesn't properly resolve the reference, or it might be that it writes it out in a way that the viewer doesn't parse properly. Also you might try it on the dartdoc that

Comment: Might be a docgen issue, or in the viewer. It is a good idea to look at the JSON that's produced, not just the display output. It might be that docgen has a problem with it, but it might also be that the viewer doesn't resolve the reference from the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Its a docgen issue/bug - can be monitored here: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=22144